# Why does the light catalyzed radical addition of tetrachloromethane to an alkene produce only a single regioisomer?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides, radicals

This reaction always occurs in the following, regiospecific way:

$$\ce{CCl4 + R-CH=CH2 ->[$h\nu$]  R-CHCl-CH2-CCl3}$$

The same should apparently also happen when there is a carbon that has two substituents (e.g. methyl groups) and yield only one major product:

$$\ce{CCl4 + (CH3)2C=CH2 ->[$h\nu$]  (CH3)2CCl-CH2-CCl3}$$

I believe the initiation step goes like this:

$$\ce{CCl4 ->[$h\nu$] CCl3^. + Cl^.}$$

Can't both of these radicals, that form in the initiation step, react with the double bond and form a secondary or tertiary radical carbon? Why does only $\ce{CCl3^.}$ apparently attack the double bond?

Comment: Is there any other information missing from this problem or in the wording of it?  I would have expected both of the radicals to react significantly, although I would expect the CCl3 radical to be a less stable intermediate than the Cl radical.

Comment: Is it not just a steric effect making the $\ce{CCl3\cdot}$ react more slowly and so the $\ce{Cl\cdot}$ wins out at the more crowded site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this reaction is highly regioselective, it is not 100% regioselective. Consider the nearly identical reactions:

$$\begin{align}
\ce{CCl4 + H2C=CH-(CH2)5CH3 ->[(PhCO2)2][90\text{-}105ºC] Cl3C-CH2-CHCl-(CH2)5CH3} \hspace{.63cm} \text{75%}^{[1]}\\
 \ce{CCl4 + H2C=CH-COH-(CH3)2 ->[(PhCO2)2][80ºC] Cl3C-CH2-CHCl-CH(OH)-(CH2)5CH3} \hspace{.63cm} \text{70%}^{[2]}\\
\end{align}
$$

Granted these reactions use radical initiators instead of light, but that wouldn't make the difference between 100% and 70-75% regioselectivity. The reality is that at the start of the reaction, $\ce{.CCl3}$ and $\ce{.Cl}$ *are* both competing to attack the alkene, and $\ce{.Cl}$ does in fact attack faster. Looking at the activation energies for the abstraction of hydrogen atoms by different radicals, we gain insight into their relative stability:

$$ \small
\begin{array}{lcc}
\hline
\text{Radical} & \ce{CH3-H} & \ce{CH3CH2-H} & \ce{(CH3)2CH-H} & \ce{(CH3)C-H}^{[3]} \\
\hline
\ce{.F} & \text{1-1.5} & \text{<1} & & \text{<1} \\
\ce{.Cl} & \text{3.4} & \text{1.1} \\
\ce{.Br} & \text{17.5} & \text{13.0} & \text{9.5} & \text{6.9} \\
\ce{.CH3} & \text{14.0} & \text{11.6} & \text{9.6} & \text{8.1} \\
\ce{.CF3} & \text{10.9} & \text{8.0} & \text{6.5} & \text{4.9} \\
\ce{.CCl3} & \text{17.9} & \text{14.2} & \text{10.6} & \text{7.7*} \\
\hline
_{^* \text{units are } \mathrm{kcal\ mol^{-1}}}
\end{array}
$$

As this reaction continues, however, chlorine atoms are abstracted from $\ce{CCl4}$, creating the product along with $\ce{.CCl3}$ radicals. Abstraction of $\ce{.CCl3}$ is highly disfavored due to steric effects. Thus, the radical chain reaction is as follows:

$$\ce{CCl4 ->[$h\nu$] .CCl3 + Cl.}$$

$$\ce{.CCl3 + CH2=CH-R ->  Cl3C-CH2-\stackrel{\displaystyle .}{\ce{C}}H-R}$$

$$\ce{Cl3C-CH2-\stackrel{\displaystyle .}{\ce{C}}H-R + CCl4 ->  Cl3C-CH2-CHCl-R + .CCl3}$$

The less than ideal yields of the radical addition of $\ce{CCl4}$ can be attributed to the strength of the $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond (higher activation energies correspond to slower rates of reactions). Because $\ce{CCl4}$ is in competition with the polymerization of the $\ce{.CCl3}$-alkene adduct, $\ce{BrCCl3}$ and $\ce{CBr4}$ are generally preferred for their higher selectivity, owed to the lower strength of the $\ce{C-Br}$ bond. One such example is shown below.

$$\ce{BrCCl3 + H2C=C(C2H5)2 ->[$h \nu$] Cl3C-CH2-CBr(C2H5)2} \hspace{1cm} {\text{91%}^{[4]}}$$

---

<sub>$^{[1]}$[M. S. Kharasch, E. W. Jensen, and W. H. Urry, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **69**, 1100 (1947).](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01197a035)

$^{[2]}$[P. D. Klemmensen, H. Kolind-Andersen, H. B. Madsen, and A. Svendsen, *J. Org. Chem.*, **44**, 416 (1979).](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo01317a023)

$^{[3]}$[F. A. Carey, R. J. Sundberg, *Advanced Organic Chemistry Part A: Structure and Mechanisms*, Springer Science, New York, **2007**, pg. 1034.](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387448978)

$^{[4]}$[M. S. Kharasch and M. Sage, *J. Org. Chem.*, **14**, 537 (1949).](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo01156a006)</sub>